# Memory architecture with self reference structure in C

Tags: c, memory-management, self-reference

I have a structure named `container`.
This structure has a pointer of type void named `obj_mem`, which will point to some allocated memory.
 
As this memory has to be able to hold different structure, I keep track of the adress and the type of each element it contains(`adress_obj`, `type_obj`) for access and casting.
 
The last property my `container` struct is that it has a self reference `child`.
 
So at running time, the user can create children of a container and add object to them.

```
typedef enum tob{ //type of object
   obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4 ...
}t_tob;

typedef struct obj1{
   //declare some stuff
}t_obj1;

typedef struct obj2{
   //declare some stuff
}t_obj2;

typedef struct obj3{
   //declare some stuff
}t_obj3;

typedef struct obj4{
   //declare some stuff
}t_obj4;

typedef struct container{
    int                name_size;
    char*              name;
    int                nmbr_obj;
    t_tob*             type_obj;
    char*              adress_obj;
    void*              mem_obj;
    int                nmbr_child;
    struct container*  child;
}t_container;
```

Then I have a function which process the whole data:
 
   It process the object in the `obj_mem` of a container.
 
   Then iterate through his children and process their object. 
 
   Then iterate through the children of his children and process their 
   object
 
   ect ... Until the end of the tree.

**The problem:**
 
I'm pretty new to programming and I'm not sure it's the right way to do this.
This code will lead to a lot of malloc call, so the memory won't be contiguous, is this a problem ?
Is there any more elegant way of doing this dynamic type of things ?
Do you have any books who could help me learning more on this kind of memory architecture ?
I'm sorry if this post can look a bit blurry but this is how I feel right now.
 

 Thanks for thelp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the memory won't be contiguous, is this a problem ?

It isn't a *problem*, but it will hurt performance.

Using better memory locality (continuous memory rather than fragmented memory) helps the CPU utilize it's cache and minimizes cache misses, which can be a very big thing where performance is concerned.

But this isn't really the most important part. You can always optimize this a little later. The most important part is that the data structure actually does what it needs to do.

> Is there any more elegant way of doing this dynamic type of things ?

Probably, but I'm not sure what you want to do, so I can't help you.

Normally when writing a dynamic type system, the type of an object is part of the object, i.e.:

```
struct my_object_s {
   unsigned int type;
   /* common type data*/
   struct vtable_s * vtable;
};

struct my_string_s {
   struct my_object_s header;
   size_t len;
   char str[];
}
```

This allows an object to be independent from it's container.

> Do you have any books who could help me learning more on this kind of memory architecture ?

I read most of what I know on the internet (I do have a few books, but not many of them go into hardware architecture).

#### EDIT (answer to comment)

You can find far more comprehensive information about Object Oriented Programming with C [here](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf). The author has done extensive work explaining the concepts and these same ideas are often used (in part or in whole) when authoring dynamic types.

For example, by having a virtual function table, casting can be avoided entirely.

On the other hand, it's common to use a switch statement when you have a limited set of types.

```
enum my_type_enum {
  /** A simple flag object object (`my_object_s`) for NULL. */
  MY_NULL,
  /** A simple flag  object (`my_object_s`) for OK. */
  MY_OK,
  /** A simple flag object (`my_err_s`) that indicates an error. */
  MY_ERR,
  /** A Number object object (`my_number_s`). */
  MY_NUMBER,
  /** A String object (`my_string_s`). */
  MY_STRING,
  /** An Array object object (`my_array_s`). */
  MY_ARRAY,
};

typedef struct { enum my_type_enum type; } my_object_s;

typedef struct {
  my_object_s header;
  size_t len;
  char str[];
} my_string_s;

void example_usage(my_object_s *obj) {
  switch (obj->type) {
  case MY_STRING:
    printf("String: %s", ((my_string_s *)obj)->str);
    break;
  default:
    printf("whatever...");
  }
}
```

Notice that by having `my_object_s` as the header for each one of the types, you can safely access the header data as if any pointer to an object was a `my_object_s *` and this way you can discern it's underlying type.

Comment: Hey Mist thanks for the answer, I'm not sure to understand your example for the dynamic type system. You suggest that I hold the type in each of my object structure ? How will the cast then be performed ? I mean If I want to access the first object  of a container. I got his adresse in container.adress_obj[0]; but how can I cast it if the type is owned by the object ?

Comment: @soall - I added more information an and example to my answer, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If your container has to hold a data tree such  a structure is pretty much required in some form. The one thing that really seemed odd is that your type of object member is a pointer, that would usually be a simple value.